# How to get the accuracy of the calibration in millimeters not in pixels?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera-calibration

I'd like to know the accuracy of the camera's calibration status in millimeter units. In other words, what does the X pixels error (the Root Mean Square error) in the 2D image correspond to the distance in millimeters in the 3D object coordinate system?

In OpenCV, I can get the accuracy of the calibration based on the Root Mean Square error (pixel units) as a result of `calibrateCamera` function. Or, I can manually calculate by reprojecting the object points to the image with `projectPoints` and by comparing them with the current image points.

For example, let's say I got the RMS error around 2.0. Does this mean 5mm or 10mm difference? How to calculate the conversion from pixels in 2d to millimeters in 3d? Note that the ArUco marker is always placed horizontally and I know the size of the marker.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate your projection 2d error you have to use your camera sensor phisical dimensions to determine pixel width and height.

There is no simple way to determine 3d mm error. Are you using single or multi camera setup? If you are using single camera you cant determine real 3d coordinates based on their projection without depth map.

In multicamera system there is some workaround. You can measure distances between corners detected on both cameras (in 3d) and compare it to marker dimension or try to fit plane to whole board.

Comment: I already have 2d projection error in pixel units and I'd like to know how to get 3D mm units error. I use a single camera, but I know the size, position, and pose of the marker. Is it impossible to get millimeter error (x and y axes)? If so, could you explain why? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It is possible to use your calibration to find intersection of light ray and pattern plane. But it is not proper. Why? Because it is not good practise to measure accuracy of calibration with references got from that calibration. You dont have measured 3d coordinates in camera coordinate system, and the pose is obtained from calibration. Value of mm 3d error in that case would be low.

Comment: Could you let me know how to calculate the 3D error from 2D RMS error (pixel)? I just want to know what is the meaning of xx pixels error in 3D world.

Comment: XX pixel error represents quality of calibration. In my opinion there is no easy way to calculate 3d error without any additional information.

Comment: As written above, I have camera matrix, camera pose,  marker size, marker pose and position. Object points and image points are also known. What else do you need? Please share your idea if you have something in your mind.